# How to pass parameter to Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, parameters

I am able to trigger a new Jenkins build every time code is committed into GitHub.

Example of a Jenkinsfile in GitHub:

```
node ('aws-slaves') {
    stage ('Gate 1: Checkout Code') {
        wrap([$class: 'TimestamperBuildWrapper']) {
            echo "Deleting dir"
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
}
```

How do I pass parameter from another GitHub file (that is in the same repo) and print parameter value?

Comment: `node` in that script isn't NodeJS, you realise? It's part of Jenkins' own declarative DSL (which is written in Groovy, not JavaScript). If you want to provide parameters to the build, see e.g. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Comment: I'll take that as a *"no I didn't realise"*! What do you mean *"pass parameter from another GitHub link"*? Check out a separate repo into the workspace, or create a parameterised build (see previous comment), or ...?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have 1 github Jenkins file and have another file in the same repo that holds a variable (parameter) value. How to load parameter from that github file during Jenkins build (and just print it out)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"GitHub file"*? Do you just mean some other file in the same repo? In that case it's accessible in the workspace like every other file, assuming you `checkout scm` or similar. It's not at all clear from your question what the specific problem you're trying to solve is, so it's all but unanswerable as posted.

Comment: Yes - some other file inside the same repo. e.g. 'file1' that holds value 'variable1'.

Comment: `sh 'cat location/of/file1'`? Again (and partictularly given that printing stuff is generally not a useful task to set a Jenkins build to) it's not clear what you're *actually trying to achieve*. Maybe check out e.g. https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/

Comment: I am brand new to Jenkins so trying to learn how to pass parameters to a build. e.g. want to run a simple script that will display e.g. date and load variable from another file in github (in the same repo) and print value of that. Not sure if CAT can get a value from a github file (since file is not on a server machine where jenkins will execute - or is it jenkins cloning the whole repo during the build so that CAT can be executed?).

Comment: Saying *"a github file"* has no real meaning, it seems like you're just referring to a file in the repo. Passing parameters to a build can be done when you kick it off (start from e.g. https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines), separately from the files in the repo it's building. If you don't actually have a build task to perform, probably Jenkins isn't the right tool.

Comment: Jenkins is needed and trying to learn steps - if you can help - please do. How do you call a file that is in a github repo? (e.g. parameter file) Can the value of it be loaded during a jenkins build? I am trying to build a more complicated build later but this is needed step.

Answer (score 2):

I was exploring different ways to do it and here is one way:

Inside a Jenkins file - you can set to execute a 'shell' script. One of the commands from a shell script can be 'curl'. With a curl command - value from a GitHub repository (from a specific file in it) can be printed to a screen, it can be saved into a file or stored in temporary variable. In that way - build can be parametrized via github by storing specific values in separate files (in github repository) and content of a file can be read during a build.

Another way is to use a jenkins hook inside github which will trigger a build every time code is committed. During that build - whole github repository (where code is committed) will be fetched and stored inside temporary directory on a server where Jenkins is running. From that (local) folder - any file from a (cloned) repository can be read into a variable and in that way parameterization can be achieved as well.